# CSV Import: undefined method `path'

Tags: ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to import a CSV with addresses. I am requiring 'csv' at the controller. However I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in AddressesController#import_addresses

undefined method `path' for "testimport.csv":String

 Address.import(params[:file].path)
```

Address Controller

```
class AddressesController < ApplicationController

  require 'csv'

  def import_addresses
    Address.import(params[:file].path)
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Addresses imported."
  end
```

Address Model

```
def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file, headers: true) do |row|
        Address.create! row.to_hash
    end
end
```

Reference: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Comment: does form include `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. without this `input type="file"`'s value will be sent with just filename

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this

```
form_tag(import_addresses_path, :multipart => true) do
```

The multipart option is not part of the url_for options. so you have to make them explicitly separate*

The form_tag isn't generated right and string is sent to controller, not the object.

Comment: This was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have written Address Model as this :-

```
def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file, headers: true) do |row|
        Address.create! row.to_hash
    end
end
```

I think if you change a bit like the following,it should work :-

```
def self.import(file)
        CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
            Address.create! row.to_hash
        end
    end
```

Hope it works !

Comment: Hi Debasish, I have added the file.path but still get an error. undefined method `path' for "insert_direcciones_TEST.csv":String CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|

Answer (score 0):

This is your code:

```
Address.import(   params[:file].path   )
```

I added a couple of spaces... do you see the problem?

`params[:file]` is a String

The String class does not have a `path` method

That's the error you are seeing.

Just remove `.path` and it should work

Comment: Hi Tilo, I removed .path, however I still get an error. Errno::ENOENT in AddressesController#import_addresses No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - insert_direcciones_TEST.csv ...CSV.foreach(file, headers: true) do |row|

Comment: you need to set params[:file] to the filename on your local machine which needs to be imported

Comment: @Lut You need to send full path as string which needs to be imported.

Comment: it's usually a good idea not to assume what the current working directory is - using absolute paths is much safer